# Yii multiple table deletion not working

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have two table : `user` and `userProfile`.
I want to delete record from both table by using Yii Active Record.

Following is my code:

```
public function actionDelete($id) {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);
        User::model()->deleteAll('user_id=:id', array(':id' => $model->user_id));

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if (!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
```

Following is the relation between two models:

```
public function relations() {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'userProfiles' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserProfile', 'user_id'),
        );
    }

public function relations() {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        );
    }
```

Here first I am deleting the record from userProfile table (which is working fine) and after that getting the `user_id` from that model and by passing it to deleteAll method I am trying to delete record from `user` table but its returning `error 404 the requested page does not exist.` error.

Is it proper deletion method? or Where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what is happening is after deleting the record your again trying to get the info of that model which is already being deleted so u get the error error `404 the requested page does not exist .`

If you want to achieve that then you need to take the id of the model that you are deleting in a separate variable and further using that variable to delete the another record

Comment: Yes you are correct. That was the issue and solved it. Thanks ninad :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function actionDelete($id) {        
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);

         $user_id = $model->user_id; // after user profile is deleted, the model still hold old information, but this line just makes sure everything would work correct whether Yii version you was using

        $model->delete();
        User::model()->deleteByPK($user_id); // a user has one or more profile, it doesn't need to use deleteAll()

    // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if (!isset($_GET['ajax']))
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin')); // error 404 from here you should check about the actual url which this action use to redirect
}
```

Btw, if you want to remove user absolutely, why don't let your db do it? In MySQL, you can update the foreign key is from `RESTRICTED` to `CASCADE`, it means that once you remove the User record, it would also automatically remove the dependent record (UserProfile) by the FK, then you don't need manually handle it like this.

Edited: With amount of information I got from you, maybe out there are something wrong. I suggest you enable log and see the log of SQL implementation

Enable Log on protected\config\main.php

```
'components'=>array(
'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, info',
//                    'categories'=>'application.*',
                    'categories'=>'system.db.CDbCommand',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),*/
            ),
        ),
)
```

Put this line on your action

```
Yii::app()->log->processLogs(null);
```

Refresh your page and open the `protected\runtime\application.log` to see what happened

Comment: Could you show me your two models (User and UserProfile) and error which you got when you tried my way?

Comment: I am getting this error : `Error 404: The requested page does not exist.`

Comment: Its deleting record from first table but not from 2nd table

Comment: First about Error 404, you should check what return from this line isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin')
Is it the valid route? Example admin/index or something?
If your site reached to line redirect, it means that there was no error when execute the query, but if you want to debug it, you have to skip the redirect line, and troubleshoot after UserProFile was removed, then echo to see what value is variable $user_id

Answer (score 0):

Its not a `deleteAll` method fault. You delete record `$id` here:

```
 $this->loadModel($id)->delete();
```

Then you call

```
$this->loadModel($id);
```

In loadmodel method you have following code:

```
if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
```

You deleted it already, so its null and you getting your error.

Make `loadmodel($id)->delete` and then

```
$model=User::model()->find('id=:id',array(':id'=>$id));
$model->delete();
```

This will work like you need.

Comment: @ Here, I am deleting the record from userProfile table by using its primary key field "user_profile_id" and after that using "user_profile_id" field I am getting the "user_id" field which I am passing in user table for deletion.

Comment: its still deleting record from single table

Comment: do like this 1st: `$model = $this->loadModel($id);` 2nd: `User::model()->deleteAll('user_id=:id', array(':id' => $model->user_id));` 3rd: `$model->delete()` Thats all. Nothing else needed.

Comment: It'll not work becoz I need to first delete record from `userProfile` table then and then it will allow me to delete record from `user` table. (Foreign key reference issue)

Comment: Here is error its showing : `Error 500: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`safehands_in`.`user_profile`, CONSTRAINT `fk_up_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

Comment: Whatever I have posted that is correct but don't know why its not working

Comment: Only this query is not working : `User::model()->deleteAll('user_id=:id', array(':id' => $model->user_id));`

Comment: you have many users with 1 profile then do like this: `$users=User::model()->findAll('user_id=:id',array(':id'=>$model->user_id)); foreach ($users as $key=>$user){ $user->delete();}`

Comment: No its not like many users with 1 profile. I have user information like username, pwd in "user" table and general info like fn,ln, etc in "userprofile" table. Thats it.